# How to create dictionary from different length of list in python

Tags: python, list, dictionary

I have a list of x like this:

```
x =[[[1, 2]], [[2, 1], [2, 3]], [[3, 2]], [[4, 7, 6, 5]]]
```

And I try to create a list of dictionary in final result like this:

```
dict_list = [{"user_idx": 1, "partner_1": 2}, {"user_idx": 2, "partner_1": 1, "partner_2": 3}, 
            {"user_idx": 3, "partner_1": 2}, {"user_idx": 4, "partner_1":7, "partner_2": 6,"partner_3":5}]
```

How can I complete it with python code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try:

```py
x =[[[1, 2]], [[2, 1], [2, 3]], [[3, 2]], [[4, 7, 6, 5]]]

out = {}
for g in x:
    for subl in g:
        out.setdefault(subl[0], []).extend(subl[1:])

out = [
    {
        "user_idx": k,
        **{"partner_{}".format(idx): i for idx, i in enumerate(v, 1)},
    }
    for k, v in out.items()
]
print(out)
```

Prints:

```py
[
    {"user_idx": 1, "partner_1": 2},
    {"user_idx": 2, "partner_1": 1, "partner_2": 3},
    {"user_idx": 3, "partner_1": 2},
    {"user_idx": 4, "partner_1": 7, "partner_2": 6, "partner_3": 5},
]
```

Comment: thanks so much sir, your solution works well and made me complete what I want.

Answer (score 1):

This clearly needs a single list comprehension solution, though admittedly this is getting a bit out of hands:

```
dict_list = [
    {"user_idx": (s := list(chain.from_iterable(z if i == 0 else z[1:] 
                                   for i, z in enumerate(el))))[0],
     **{f"partner_{ii + 1}": p for ii, p in enumerate(s[1:])}}
     for el in x]
print(dict_list)

# Out:
[{'user_idx': 1, 'partner_1': 2}, 
 {'user_idx': 2, 'partner_1': 1, 'partner_2': 3}, 
 {'user_idx': 3, 'partner_1': 2}, 
 {'user_idx': 4, 'partner_1': 7, 'partner_2': 6, 'partner_3': 5}]
```

Comment: thanks a lot for your awesome solution. However, I try to follow your recommendation but it does not work if the coder forget to import itertools before running this code.

Thus, the finally code should be like this: 
       import itertools dict_list = [
         {"user_idx": (s := list(itertools.chain.from_iterable(z if i == 0 else z[1:] 
                                   for i, z in enumerate(el))))[0],
         **{f"partner_{ii + 1}": p for ii, p in enumerate(s[1:])}}
         for el in x]
print(dict_list)

Comment: Very true, sorry, should have added the import